# Is there a way to generate a phrase based on two column entries?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I’m not sure how to go about this or if I’ll even explain it correctly, so bare with me.
I’m trying to make a spreadsheet for rotational play in The Sims 4 so I can maybe have fun with the game again.
I was curious if there was a way that if I had two columns with data validation from two other sheets in the main document, if there was a way for me to be like “okay so astronaut - smuggler branch” is in one column, and I have the level, let’s say 8 also in a data validation in the column next to it, if there is a way to generate “job title for level”
I have no idea lol I’m kind of high and at a loss for words ᕕ( ᐛ )ᕗ

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.